# ERRO LÓGICO EN UNA CONSULTA EN MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

Mi objetivo es mostrar todos los partidos que ha jugado un equipo, mi problema comienza cuando quiero mostrar mediante el `WHERE`los partidos que ha ganado como local y visitante.

Si solo muestro los partidos como local no hay problema con el código:

```
SELECT semana, local.nom_equipo, goles_loc, visitante.nom_equipo, goles_vis, (goles_loc = goles_vis) AS Ganador FROM partidos 
JOIN equipos local ON partidos.num_eqpo_loc = local.num_eqpo 
JOIN equipos visitante ON partidos.num_eqpo_vis = visitante.num_eqpo
WHERE local.nom_equipo = 'Cruz Azul'
ORDER BY semana;
```

Pero si agrego un `AND`para que también me muestre los que jugó como visitante la consulta no me arroja nada.
¿por qué será eso? ¿cuál es mi error lógico?

```
SELECT semana, local.nom_equipo, goles_loc, visitante.nom_equipo, goles_vis, (goles_loc = goles_vis) AS Ganador FROM partidos 
JOIN equipos local ON partidos.num_eqpo_loc = local.num_eqpo 
JOIN equipos visitante ON partidos.num_eqpo_vis = visitante.num_eqpo
WHERE local.nom_equipo = 'Cruz Azul' AND visitante.nom_equipo = 'Cruz Azul'
ORDER BY semana;
```

[image: IMAGEN DE LA TABLA VACÍA]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta es mi interpretacion, puede que este mal, si es asi corrígeme sin pena. 
Tienes una base de Datos donde en una tabla Partidos tienes 2 id que corresponden a la tabla Equipos, o sea que un partido esta conformado por 2 equipos (local y visitante).
Si es asi entonces un partido no puede tener el mismo equipo de visitante y local.

Partiendo de esto si usas *AND* eso es lo que estas pidiendo (un partido con el equipo "Cruz Azul" de visitante y local) 
intenta en vez de *AND* utilizar *OR* y de esta forma buscas todos los partidos donde el equipo "Cruz Azul" este de visitante o de local, que supongo es lo que buscas.

Saludos, espero haber ayudado

Comment: Efectivamente tenias razón, los `id` de los equipos son FK que conectan al `id` de la tabla que contiene los equipos.
Muchas gracias por la explicación me fue de gran ayuda.